# why can't rsh get the error message from a remote server

Tags: shell

I use rsh to execute some commands in a remote server .

if the command or the parameters of the command is valid , everything goes smoothly . but
if the command is not valid or the parameters of the command is not valid nothing returned from rsh.

so does anyone of you explain why does it happen ?  thanks.

Comment: Why are you still using `rsh` instead of the more secure `ssh`?

Comment: I second grawity's comment.  You are using the wrong tool - rsh is quite insecure.  Instead use ssh user@server "command".  ssh will return both stdout and stderr and also return exit codes.

Answer (score 1):

How are you running rsh? Manually or via a script/program?

Are you capturing stderr as well as stdout? Try adding `2>&1` to the end of your command to make stderr be redirect to stdout.